# Apply transformation on CSV file columns without using array in Logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I need to apply some transformation for CSV file format content with 40+ columns.
Is there way to apply transformation without converting the content to array format.
If I am using select activity I need to pass 40 columns as well with headers hard coded.

Please suggest if any other possible option is available.

Below are the steps I am using now.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One of the workaround could be possible we can use **Parse csv** activity instead of that .Select all the headers that are present in your csv file
as shown below:

[image]

[image]

For more information please refer the below links:

- [How to parse a CSV file using Microsoft Power Automate or Azure Logic Apps| BLOG](https://medium.com/plumsail/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-using-microsoft-flow-azure-logic-apps-or-powerapps-e8f6f44d7f6b)
- [Perform data operations in Azure Logic Apps| MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#create-csv-table-action)

Comment: thanks, will try and test it